# Does each AWS VPC endpoint require individual IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint

I am trying to create VPC endpoints to AWS service. There are eleven of them including ec2, ssm, secretsmanager etc. I am getting the below error during deployment for the VPC endpoints.

```
InsufficientFreeAddressesInSubnet: Insufficient free addresses to allocate an addresses in subnet
```

Does each endpoint assigned a separate IP address?

Comment: Yes, it does require IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the creation of a VPC endpoint implies the creation of a network interface, thus free IP addresses are required. From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html):

> For each subnet that you specify from your VPC, we create an endpoint network interface in the subnet and assign it a private IP address from the subnet address range. An endpoint network interface is a requester-managed network interface; you can view it in your AWS account, but you can't manage it yourself.

This however is not the case for gateway endpoints, although only few services such as S3 are supported by those.